# Search a collection for a models that have an attribute like and search param

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone.js-collections, backbone-model

I am wanting to search my collections for models that match closely to what the user is typing in to a search box,

For example I have 3 models in a collection with each model has it's own name attribute and they are named as follows,

1) Apples Are Red
2) Apples Are Green
3) Apples Can Be Yellow

The users inputs into the search "Apple" and at the moment, my code will return nothing as it is not an exact match I am using,

`var found_models = this.where({ "name" : filterValue });`

Is there a way to return all the models that match a string, the search happens on every keyup.

Comment: You have to use `_.filter` instead of `_.where`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `_.filter` in conjunction with Regexp:

```
var found_models = this.filter(function(model) {
    return /apple/i.test(model.get('name'));
});
```